# WHy is my leaderboard command for my leveling system not working

Tags: python, discord.py

So i recently implemented a leaderboard command to my leveling system but it doesn't work no errors pop up, like when I type -asdfghjhgf my bot says cmd not found do -help for a list of cmds but when I do -leaderboard nothing comes up
here is my code

```py
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    top_users = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

    names = ''
    for postion, user in enumerate(top_users):
        # add 1 to postion to make the index start from 1
        names += f'{postion+1} - <@!{user}> with {top_users[user]}\n'

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard")
    embed.add_field(name="Names", value=names, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

if you were wondering my users.json file is formated
`userid, xp ,lvl`
ppl need my users.json file so here

```json
{"466969761033748490": {"experience": 730, "level": 5}, "832560001758789682": {"experience": 240, "level": 3}, "788864044413091853": {"experience": 5, "level": 1}}
```

Comment: I would check the users.json file.

If you are getting an array of records, it should at least have braces. The way you are iterating over the data leads me to believe you are expecting it to be an list of lists. Please post at least the first few lines of your users.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is real close. Your source data is an object where its keys are the user id, with each key pointing to the user's data.

I think the problem with your sorting is how you're using the item.

```
top_users = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['experience'], reverse=True)}

names = ''
for position, (user, value) in enumerate(top_users):
    # add 1 to postion to make the index start from 1
    names += f'{postion+1} - <@!{user}> with {value}\n'
```

You'll get a list of pairs with the key as the first element, the sub-object as the second.